# Handlers and multiple Activities

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, android-bluetooth

Ok, I am new to android, I'm trying to create an app that interfaces with an arduino via bluetooth. I've seen the sample BluetoothChat and seen how it's using an Handler to communicate between the "service", the threads spawned by it and the MainActivity.
My problem is that I have more than one Activity that needs to use the Bluetooth Service.
For each Activity I have an Handler like this:

```
        mHandler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            switch (message.what){
           case BtService.CHANGE_STATE:
               if (message.arg1 == BtService.STATE_CONNECTING){
                   Intent i = new Intent (MainActivity.this,ConnectedActivity.class);
                   startActivity(i);

               }
               break;
           }
        }

    };
```

and in the service constructor I've got this:

```
    private BtService(){
    btm = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    mHandler= new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
}
```

and when I need to send a message I do this:

```
    private synchronized void setState(int state){
    mHandler.obtainMessage(CHANGE_STATE, state, -1).sendToTarget();
    mState = state;
}
```

but the messages aren't received in the various other Handlers.
In [here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html) is stated that "all of the Handler objects for a particular thread receive the same message." so I can't understand the problem.
Do I need, every time an activity is started, to pass to the service the Handler declared in that Activity to have it receive messages? This seems to work, but it dosen't seem to be a good practice for me.

Answer (score 5):

If you want send the message in all application you should use BroadcastReceiver, I this this is the best way in your case.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(ApplicationConstants.MY_MESSAGE);
 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Receive message in any activity(you cand use this in more then one activity)

```
   BroadcastReceiver connectionUpdates = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {

                     ...//TODO here
        }
    };
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
            connectionUpdates ,
            new IntentFilter(ApplicationConstants.MY_MESSAGE));
```

Hope this is helpfull

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having each activity connect through bluetooth, you can extend the Application layer and use that to maintain thread(s) to retrieve and manage the data collected over the bluetooth connection.  Then just use a handler in each activity to have them refresh against the data gathered in the Application layer, if needed.

My only Activity with the btAdapter and socket is the first activity to actually need bluetooth information (after menus and bt config activities).

In my first activity onRusume() looks something like this with comments explaining..:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
super.onResume();

Log.d(TAG, "...onResume - try connect...");

// Set up a pointer to the remote node using it's address.
BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

// Two things are needed to make a connection:
//   A MAC address, which we got above.
//   A Service ID or UUID.  In this case we are using the
//     UUID for SPP.
try {
  btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
} catch (IOException e) {
  errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and socket create failed: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
}

// Discovery is resource intensive.  Make sure it isn't going on
// when you attempt to connect and pass your message.
btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

// Establish the connection.  This will block until it connects.
Log.d(TAG, "...Connecting...");
try {
  btSocket.connect();
  Log.d(TAG, "....Connection ok...");
} catch (IOException e) {
  try {
    btSocket.close();
  } catch (IOException e2) {
    errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and unable to close socket during connection failure" + e2.getMessage() + ".");
  }
}

// Create a data stream so we can talk to server.
Log.d(TAG, "...Create Socket...");

/**
 * **Here I am kicking off the thread in the application that retrieves all data
 * needed by all my activities.  Then it stores the information in its member
 * variables.  Each activity then refreshes as often as needed, gets the data from
 * the application layer it needs and does some logic on it.**
 */
if(mConnectedThread == null) {
    mConnectedThread = app.new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
    mConnectedThread.start();
}

// This kicks off the handler for this activity that refreshes the activity every
// xxxx ms  and checks the data retrieved from bt in the application layer.
startUpdatingTicketView();
}
```

That is pretty much the core of how i got it to work for me.

Just an additional note...  I also tried doing this with the bt communication managed in a background service and could not get it working well.  I forget exactly what the issues I was running into were and it is quite possible using a service would work as well, but I did not end up going this route.

Good luck.

Comment: Sorry if I haven't made myself clear, but the "true" question was: "Is it true that all Handlers of a thread receive the same messages, as stated in the API training or not, or if I'm understanding it wrong". Anyway, thank you for your answer